# "Runaway argument" when running exporting to PDF with hyperlinks

Tags: org-export, latex

I have been trying to do my resume in org-mode and export it to pdf with `org-latex-export-to-pdf`. I have almost gotten it just the way I want it, but for some reason whenever I try to add a hyperlink to the resume (to a github project, for example), and run the export command, I get a message in the echo area:

```
Process completed with errors: Runaway argument
```

When I go to the `Org PDF LaTeX Output` buffer, I see a bunch of warnings like this:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\<let>-command' on input line 97.
```

There are many lines like this all from the same input line (the line with the hyperlink) but with a different `removing...` message. I have been using org-mode and Emacs for a little while now, but I just started learning LaTeX yesterday, so the errors are a little difficult for me to debug. Any idea what is going wrong here?

## Update:

Here is the line in the generated `.tex` file:

```
\subsection{EmacsBehavior - \url{https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.emacs.html}}
```

generated from this line in the `.org` file:

```
*** EmacsBehavior - https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.emacs.html
```

Comment: I typically debug Org export failures by opening the generated TeX file and figuring out what part of it causes the error by bisecting it.

Comment: @wasamasa I did do that, and I can see that if I have a hyperlink in my document that is what causes it, but I am not sure why it causes the error or how to add hyperlinks the right way...

Comment: Could you show us the generated latex hyperlink?

Comment: The ulr appears inside a command argument, that's the problem.

Comment: Besides the warning, the generated pdf is ok, right?  On the latex side, adding `\protect` just in front of `\url` removes the warnings.

Comment: @JeanPierre Ah, you mean because the \url{} is nested in the \subsection{}? Yes, it does seem to be generated as expected, and the hperlinks work